# Plasma Networks applet: hide networks

Tags: wireless, kde, indicator, plasma, applet

Is there a way to hide wifi networks from the applet? 
Where I work we have 3 different wifi networks. Also, there are other offices with their networks and I would like to hide them so I can see only ours.
Is this possible?